# List Overflowing Into Div

Tags: html, css

Thank you for any help in advance.

Take a look here: http://www.martialgear.com/martial-arts-gear/sparring-gear.html

Put your mouse over the first product, Padded Weapons Protective Headgear

Note how the entire category section above changes color on hover. This makes me for some reason the ordered list is overlapping the DIV sections above it. What is supposed to happen is only the product section's background switches color.

It works for the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th products and so on.

I have tried various adjustments on the CSS and html but cannot get this right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because all the elements above the first product are floated and never cleared.

A simple fix is to add this to your css:

```css
#products-list {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, your Ordered List `<ol>` is followed directly by a `<div>`, which is followed by an `<li>`. The `<li>` should go directly after the `<ol>`.

Here is what you have:

```
<ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <div id="product-listing" onclick="location.href='http://www.martialgear.com/martial-arts-gear/sparring-gear/padded-weapons-protective-headgear.html';" style="cursor:pointer;" class="odd">
    <li class="item">
```

Try changing this to

```
<ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <li class="item">
    <div id="product-listing" onclick="location.href='http://www.martialgear.com/martial-arts-gear/sparring-gear/padded-weapons-protective-headgear.html';" style="cursor:pointer;" class="odd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entire thing is inside class "item" and you have following code.

```
.products-list li.item {border-bottom:1px solid #d9ddd3; padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; }
.products-list li.item:hover { background:#EEEEEE; }
```

So when you are hovering over product you are actually hovering over "item".
Remove

```
.products-list li.item:hover { background:#EEEEEE; }
```

And add similar hover to the specific element you want color change on hover.